# Rotate a sentence , each word at an increasing inclination

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to rotate the sentence `"share it with your friends"` with every word at an increased inclination with respect to the previous word. ie. inclination of the words should be as follows.

- share = 0 degrees
- it = x degrees
- with = 2x degrees
- your = 3x degrees
- friends = 4x degrees

Comment: So where exactly is the problem here? We can't know, where you are stuck with this little information.

Comment: i've tried splitting the sentence into words and adding each to separate divs and css rotating each div. Is that the only method to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using CSS's [`transform`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform) with *rotate* and give an origin of `0`. You have to do it on a block-styled element.

```html
<div class="a">share <div class="b">it <div class="b">with <div class="b">your <div class="b">friends</div></div></div></div></div>
```

```css
.a, .b {display: inline-block;}
.b {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-10deg);
    -webkit-transform-origin: 0;
    -moz-transform: rotate(-10deg);
    -moz-transform-origin: 0;
    transform: rotate(-10deg);
    transform-origin: 0;
}
```

In this example, *x = 10*.

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/f77eM/1/)

Answer (score 4):

Put each word into a nested span, so that each span is inside the previous one.

Then use CSS to set the rotation on all the spans at once. This will result in each one being rotated a bit more than the previous one.

Note that you need to set the spans to `display:inline-block` in order for the rotation to take effect, and you'll need to set the rotation origin point to make them look like they still run together as a sentence.

```
<div><span>share <span>it <span>with <span>your <span>friends</span></span></span></span></span></div>
```

```
div span {
    display:inline-block;
    transform:rotate(-15deg);
    transform-origin: 0% 50%;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Chnq4/

Comment: This won't work in _Google Chrome_ because it needs the `-webkit-` prefix. Seems like wrapping it in a `<div>` solved that weird `<span>` issue I was having too. The code does look a lot nicer than my answer. +1 EDIT: Actually I just tried again with <span> in mine and now it works, must have typo'd something

Comment: Prefixed version: http://jsfiddle.net/JamesD/Chnq4/2/